How to Filter Installed Software to Only Show Apps Visible in Windows Search Bar
I have a Python script that lists all installed software by reading from the Windows registry. It pulls data from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER under SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. However, this results in a list that includes system apps, libraries, and components like “Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables” and “WebView Runtime,” which do not appear in the Windows search bar.
Goal:
I want to modify my script to only show applications that would appear in the Windows search bar when the app’s name is typed. This should exclude internal system components and services that users don’t interact with directly.
I’ve tried filtering based on certain keywords, but that approach is incomplete. Is there a way to check whether an installed app is registered to show up in the Start Menu or Windows Search? Perhaps by checking for a Start Menu shortcut or another indicator?
Here’s the basic script I’m using for fetching software data:
import winreg

def foo(hive, flag):
    aReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, hive)
    aKey = winreg.OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", 0, winreg.KEY_READ | flag)

    count_subkey = winreg.QueryInfoKey(aKey)[0]
    software_list = []

    for i in range(count_subkey):
        software = {}
        try:
            asubkey_name = winreg.EnumKey(aKey, i)
            asubkey = winreg.OpenKey(aKey, asubkey_name)
            software['name'] = winreg.QueryValueEx(asubkey, "DisplayName")[0]

            try:
                software['version'] = winreg.QueryValueEx(asubkey, "DisplayVersion")[0]
            except EnvironmentError:
                software['version'] = 'undefined'
            try:
                software['publisher'] = winreg.QueryValueEx(asubkey, "Publisher")[0]
            except EnvironmentError:
                software['publisher'] = 'undefined'
            software_list.append(software)
        except EnvironmentError:
            continue

    return software_list

software_list = foo(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY) + foo(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY) + foo(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 0)

for software in software_list:
    print('Name=%s, Version=%s, Publisher=%s' % (software['name'], software['version'], software['publisher']))


Filtering out system apps by checking for certain keywords (like Microsoft Visual C++, Redistributable, etc.), but this is not a reliable method.
Searching for a way to check if an app has a Start Menu shortcut, but I’m unsure how to integrate that into my script.

What I’m asking:

Is there a reliable way to filter the software to only show those apps that are user-facing and searchable via the Start Menu or Windows search bar?
Can this be done by checking for a Start Menu shortcut or other registration in the system?

Any guidance or pointers to the right API or method would be greatly appreciated!

I'd guess that Windows Start Menu (recursively) shows items under (merged) special folders  shell:Common Start Menu and shell:Start Menu. Absolute paths to those folders are saved in the registry  and retrieved (in cmd) as follows: reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" -v "Common Start Menu" and reg.exe query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" -v "Start Menu".
